# Flask WTForm DateField to only accept today and future dates only

Tags: python, validation, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I have a WT form, which requires data input from the front end side. Currently, the form allows the user to enter all dates but as I am creating a site which should only allow future dates to be input, I would like to add a validator to this, to not allow past dates.

I have had a look at previous questions, however, they have not been of great help.

Below is a section from my forms.py

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, SubmitField, DateField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired
from wtforms.ext.sqlalchemy.fields import QuerySelectField
from ..models import TasterDay, Course


class TasterDayForm(FlaskForm):
"""
Form for admin to add or edit a taster day
"""
name = StringField('Name', validators=[DataRequired()])
date = DateField('Date (DD-MM-YYYY)', format='%d-%m-%Y')
course = StringField('Course', validators=[DataRequired()])
lecturer = StringField('Lecturer', validators=[DataRequired()])
description = StringField('Description', validators=[DataRequired()])
submit = SubmitField('Submit')
```

Here is a section from my views.py file which shows some of the routes.

```
from flask import abort, flash, redirect, render_template, url_for
from flask_login import current_user, login_required

from . import admin
from .forms import TasterDayForm, StudentAssignForm, CourseForm
from .. import db
from ..models import TasterDay, Course, Student


def check_admin():
"""
Prevent non-admins from accessing the page
"""
if not current_user.is_admin:
    abort(403)


 # TasterDay Views

@admin.route('/tasterdays', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def list_tasterdays():
"""
List all tasterdays
"""
check_admin()

tasterdays = TasterDay.query.all()

return render_template('admin/tasterdays/tasterdays.html',
                       tasterdays=tasterdays, title="TasterDay")


@admin.route('/tasterdays/add', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def add_tasterdays():
"""
Add a Tasterday to the database
"""
check_admin()

add_tasterdays = True

form = TasterDayForm()
if form.validate_on_submit():
    tasterdays = TasterDay(name=form.name.data,
                            description=form.description.data,
                           date=form.date.data,
                           course=form.course.data,
                           lecturer=form.lecturer.data)

    try:
        # add tasterday to the database
        db.session.add(tasterdays)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('You have successfully added a new Taster Day.')
    except:
        # in case tasterday  already exists
        flash('Error: Taster Day already exists.')

    # redirect to tasterdays page
    return redirect(url_for('admin.list_tasterdays'))

# load tasterdays template
return render_template('admin/tasterdays/tasterday.html', action="Add",
                       add_tasterdays=add_tasterdays, form=form,
                       title="Add Taster Day")


@admin.route('/tasterdays/edit/<int:id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def edit_tasterdays(id):
"""
Edit a TasterDay
"""
check_admin()

add_tasterdays = False

tasterdays = TasterDay.query.get_or_404(id)
form = TasterDayForm(obj=tasterdays)
if form.validate_on_submit():
    tasterdays.name = form.name.data
    tasterdays.description = form.description.data
    tasterdays.date = form.date.data
    tasterdays.course = form.course.data
    tasterdays.lecturer = form.lecturer.data
    db.session.commit()
    flash('You have successfully edited the TasterDay.')

    # redirect to the tasterdays page
    return redirect(url_for('admin.list_tasterdays'))

form.description.data = tasterdays.description
form.name.data = tasterdays.name
form.date.data = tasterdays.date
form.course.data = tasterdays.course
form.lecturer.data = tasterdays.lecturer
return render_template('admin/tasterdays/tasterday.html', action="Edit",
                       add_tasterdays=add_tasterdays, form=form,
                       tasterdays=tasterdays, title="Edit TasterDay")
```

Could someone please explain what I need to add to ensure that past dates cannot be input in the form, and if is, throws an error.

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to figure out the answer myself.

I added `import datetime` to the top of my `forms.py` page.

Just below my `class TasterDayForm(FlaskForm):`

I added:

```
    def validate_date(form, field):
    if field.data < datetime.date.today():
        raise ValidationError("The date cannot be in the past!")
```

This works, and throws an error if the user enters a date which has passed.

Answer (score 0):

I used and voted RianneJ's answer for validate backend, but for UX and client side I used wtforms render_kw, and HTML attributes min and max so you validate full stack, Also note that the client side validation is better for user experience and faster and better performance for the server and it happens before the request is sent to the server and can prevent request from being sent to server, so it reduces the number of http requests sent to server which effects the performance of the device containing the server and also  not execute the all code in backend until reach the backend valadtion for the date value and steps required for return the response so it increase device performance and health, so client-side validation which done by wtforms using render_kw or methods is as important as backend validation, both of which are required

so answer is use `render_kw['min']` and `render_kw['max']` which are html attributes for validate date

```
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_min.asp
```

example I need to limit the expiration time for my API key for 7 months from time user form at in forms.py inside the form class

```
from wtforms.fields import DateTimeLocalField, FieldList 


expiration_date =  DateTimeLocalField('Expiration date', 
                                      validators=[InputRequired()], 
                                      format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M", default=lambda : datetime.datetime.utcnow()+relativedelta(months=+6),
                                      render_kw={
                                          'min': datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M"),
                                          'max': str((datetime.datetime.utcnow()+relativedelta(months=+6)).strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M")),
                                          }
                                    )
```

[image]

[image]

> So now the user has to set the expiry date for the key between 7
> months from the time the form is opened, note that changing the
> default, min and max values ​​happens dynamically based on the time
> the user opens the form, also note that I used the utcnow method